# Working with #hash links

Tags: php, hash

So I wish to work with #hash links..

As I cannot manipulate the history links, if HTML5 isnt supported I wish to add #photoid=12345 to the link (example).

Now how can i check in PHP if there is any in #photoid ? I cant do normally

> if(isset($_GET["photoid"])))

so what should i do here to detect where anything is in #photoid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need JavaScript for that:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
alert(hash);
```

**Edit:** you can then call on a php script and use this information. Example in [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
$.post('do_something.php', {
    // send the parameter 'hash'
    hash: hash
}, function(result) {
    // do something with the result
    // e.g. add it to a div with an id "photos":
    $('#photos').html(result);
});
```

And "do_something.php" could look like this:

```
$hash = $_POST['hash'];

// do something, e.g. retrieve a photo based on the posted hash and echo it
// this will be in the result variable that's retrieved via Javascript
echo '<img src="photo_from_hash.jpg" alt="" />';
```

Comment: Like David said, it's something that's only seen on the client side. You can use JavaScript to call on a php script though, and use the output of that script to change the page accordingly. I added an example in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. The fragment identifier is handled purely on the client and is never sent to the server so PHP can't read it.