# How can I get the full current web utl INCLUDING current #anchor?

Tags: php, http, anchor

Dear fellow earthlings, a question about the URL of a current page.

On my page there is a div with "Share this link" box, where the php has to echo the curent domain + page link, everything, including thecurrent anchor "#"

```
   <?=$currentlink?>   could be "http://website.org/language/page#anchor17"
```

Question A
is it possible for php to know and echo the full current link all the way from the first httpL//.... till #anchorxxx ?

Question B
Whats the php function to show the entire current url?

Comment: Not for PHP, no, but for JavaScript it would be.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708143/working-with-hash-links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible for php to know and echo the full current link all the way from the first httpL//.... till #anchorxxx ?

No. The fragment identifier is handled purely by the client. It is never sent to the server.

> Whats the php function to show the entire current url?

If you exclude the fragment identifier you can join it up from the various bits in `$_SERVER`. http://dev.kanngard.net/Permalinks/ID_20050507183447.html has more details.